# Passing dynamic Int variable from one class to another class in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, dynamic, sprite-kit

Am new to swift 2 and i got stuck in passing a variable from one class to another.

I have a class "GameScene" in it I have a public variable **score** and it keeps updating in update function. I want to send the **score** value at the time when two nodes collide with each other. Once it collides I go to another scene using "mainview .presentScene(**gameoverScene**)" syntax. I want the updated score in gameoverscene.

I tried using  "**private let _gameScene = GameScene()**" in gameoverscene and passing it to a lable using "**finalscore.text = String( _gameScene.finalScore)**" the variable what I get is O which I declared at the beginning but not the updated score. Pls help me in finding out the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `NSUserDefaults` to handle this.
So, in the `GameScene` just after the class `GameScene` is declared (and not in any function) I used

```
var score = Int()
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

Then in the `didMoveToView(view: SKView)` function in the same class, I used

```
defaults.setInteger(0, forKey:"score")
```

So that whenever `GameScene` is presented, the current score resets to 0 before you start the game.
Then in your collision function, before the `GameOver` scene is about to be presented (but still in the `GameScene` class), you use (after your score has been increased or decreased)

```
defaults.setInteger(score, forKey:"score")
```

This will set the current `score` to the key `"score"` in `NSUserDefaults`.

Finally, in the `GameOver` scene, before you present the score, you can say

```
let scoreFromGameScene = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("score")
label.text = "\(scoreFromGameScene)" //Or whatever you use to present the score
```

This will make sure that you get the current score from the `GameScene` so that you can use it in your `GameOver` scene. Since the key `"score"` will always have SOME integer value, we can retrieve the value without error.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 3):

If your `GameScene` has a `score` property declared as below

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var score = 0
}
```

then from any node of you game (that has been added to the main scene) you can retrieve you scene using the `scene` property. So you can do something like that.

```
class MyNode: SKNode {
    func foo() {
        guard let gameScene = self.scene as? GameScene else { 
            fatalError("This node does not belong to a GameScene")
        }
        gameScene.score = 123
    }
}
```

### Update

By you comment I understand you want to share the `score` value among multiple scenes. There are several approach to achieve this. One of the easiest if the following.

**Saving**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(123, forKey: "score")
```

**Reading**

```
let score = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("score")
```

> Please note that this way the value is stored on persistent storage and
>   when you restart the app the value is still available.

Comment: I increment the score in update method. `score = score+1` in GameScene say for example i shift from this scene to GameOverScene the score in update has a value of 50 in GameScene. I want that 50 in GameOverScene class.

Comment: @user3056032: understood, please take a look ad the update I added to my answer.

Comment: the value of this answer, to me... is priceless. Thank you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015729/access-array-in-gamescene-from-skspritenode-class-instance